# Undefined index: cc_owner in /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php

Tags: magento-1

I am using Magento ver. 1.6.2.0.
On checkout step I am getting following in popup:

> Unable to set payment method

When I checked the `exception.log` I found more details like following :

> exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined index:  cc_owner
>   in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(604) : eval()'d
>   code on line 17' in app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: i did not this line where to add and what lines to remove. please help on this issue facing on live site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following was the issue:

Some another developer had written some code line like

```
eval((base64_decode(str_rot13(strrev() ) ))));
```

after following line:

```
if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
    $quote->getBillingAddress()->setPaymentMethod(isset($data['method']) ? $data['method'] : null);
} else {
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setPaymentMethod(isset($data['method']) ? $data['method'] : null);
}
```

in `\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php` file.

When I removed this line everything worked correctly.

[This url](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1001-php-parse-error-unexpected-in-eval-d-code-on-l) helped me debugging this:

> PHP may encounter parse errors. These parse errors occur due to
>   incorrect input of the syntax. This type of syntax error can occur
>   while using the eval( ) function as well. This error occurs most often
>   due to the presence of PHP around the PHP strings which has to be
>   evaluated.